# day difference in bash

Tags: bash, дата

Как получить разницу между двумя датами в bash-script?

```
#!/bin/bash


ARG=$1
ARG=${ARG:-$(pwd)}
YEAR=`date +%Y`
MONTH=`date +%m`
DAY=`date +%d`
echo day
echo "$DAY"
echo arg is $ARG
cd $ARG
echo dirrectory is
pwd
stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$ARG"
echo starting loop
for entry in "$ARG"/*
do 
    FILE_DAY="$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%d" "$entry")"
    FILE_MONTH="$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%m" "$entry")"
    FILE_YEAR="$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y" "$entry")"
done
```

Нужно узнать разницу между текущей датой, и днем создания/модофикации файла.

Comment: В каком часовом поясе?

Answer (score 1):

получаете текущее время в секундах с начала эпохи:

```
$ date +%s
```

и время модификации (время создания, [можно считать, не фиксируется](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/110559)) файла (в тех же единицах):

```
$ stat -c %Y файл
```

вычисляете разницу:

```
$ echo $(($(date +%s)-$(stat -c %Y файл)))
```

при необходимости делите на количестве секунд, например, в сутках, чтобы получить разницу в днях.

Comment: Отлично, теперь поговорим о часовых поясах...